# HTTP request through code only. Possible or not?

Tags: javascript, python, php

I'm looking to make a URL's response only accessible through an HTTP request through JavaScript XHR / Jquery Ajax / Node Axios / Curl / whatever, you get it. For example, say you make a RESTful API request to a given URL endpoint. I want this given endpoint to only be accessible through an HTTP request through code only. Another words, I don't want people to access the URL's content via browser.

Comment: Use some authentication, then

Comment: @ADyson I am looking to avoid authentication for this particular process

Comment: Why, exactly? What is the problem with using authentication? There's really no other way. You can't just arbitrarily restrict which type of client connects to the server. That's mainly because in HTTP there is really no way of reliably determining what type of client it is. You can't prove that a connection does or does not come from a browser, or anything else.

Comment: You are requesting something that requires some level of auth ... even if you check for a string in the beginning of the code  such as : if ($_GET['code'] == "TOKEN_OR_JUST_A_STRING") {run my code} -- ofcourse using tokens will give you better security but for a service open to http request that's it...  unless you use whitelisting of ip addresses.

Comment: @ADyson I can't use authentication for a said user that does not access a web page via web browser in the first place. Cookies and Sessions are out of the question for this particular use case. You said 'You can't just arbitrarily restrict which type of client connects to the server', but I'm trying to do exactly this through HTTP request through code only.

Comment: There's no way to 100% secure an API like that. You can check for different headers, like `X-Requested-With`, but that can easily be spoofed and won't be default through anything other than Ajax. Even a browser request is really "through code only" (browsers are fetching pages through code as well). But honestly, if you would allow anyone to access it through, let's say cURL, why even bother? It's not like it will be more secure or anything.

Comment: `I can't use authentication for a said user that does not access a web page via web browser in the first place`...nonsense. millions of APIs the world over do exactly that, right now. If you thought about it for a moment you might realise that. The difference is they just tend to use things like token based authentication which don't rely on cookies and sessions.

Comment: @magnusEriksson real reason is I'm looking for people to apply to an application of mine via a trivial code script that they need to figure out to pass. I want to verify that they know how to make an HTTP request without going to the given URL in an address bar to get the secret key.

Comment: @ADyson read my previous comment

Comment: Then include some instruction that they need to send in some specific custom header with the request containing some specific value, like: `X-FOO: BAR`. If you just browse to the URL, it won't be present.

Comment: And/or make the request require a PUT or POST or something - again something that a browser won't do if you just browse to the URL

Comment: @ADyson excuse my ignorance here. How do I restrict URL request to require a PUT or POST request? I've never heard of that before.

Comment: Simplest way would be to just check what the variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` contains. When going to a URL through the browser, it will contain `GET`

Comment: Just so you know, no matter what you do here, anyone can just open any program like Postman and make any type of request from that application directly without writing a single line of code. So again, you can never know how that request was made. Your server only knows what the client that makes the request tells you.

Comment: @magnusEriksson not sure exactly what you mean by your previous comment. I am familiar with Postman but cannot relate. Although I do get what you mean by the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == GET.

Comment: You want people to make a request using code, but they can just as easily just open Postman and make the request from there instead. Your server won't know the difference. Any requirement (adding headers, requiring some specific http method) can also be done from Postman. My point is that if you want to see if they know how to make a HTTP request through code, ask them to send in their code and check that instead. Your server can never know if a request was made through code or through some application like Postman.

Comment: @magnusEriksson I see what you are saying now. I would still like to know if there is a more spoof-proof way to restricting browser requests. I'm sure it can still be done.

Comment: You already got two options. Make them add a custom header and/or use some other method than GET (like PUT/POST). That's about how spoof-proof you can get.

Comment: @magnusEriksson You got me two steps ahead. I appreciate it man.

Answer (score 1):

If the API expects for example a custom header (`X-Called-By=not a browser`) then it is unlikely that someone will accidentally navigate to that content using a browser.

However, this doesn't add to the security of the system. If you want to protect the API from unintended users, then use authentication and authorization.